# Quicksort java with median of first 3 elements

Tags: java, quicksort, median

I am having trouble getting a quicksort to work. My homework assignment requires that I make the pivot be the median of the first 3 elements, or the first element if the list is < 3. When I do that the sort falls apart and some elements are overwritten with other elements. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but here is the code:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partition(ArrayList<E> list, int first, int last) {
    ArrayList<E> subList = new ArrayList<E>(list.subList(first, last));
    E pivot = list.get(0);

    int low = first + 1; // Index for forward search
    int high = last; // Index for backward search

    if(list.get(0).getClass().equals(String.class)){
        while (high > low) {
            // Search forward from left
            while (low <= high && list.get(low).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.toString()) <= 0)
                low++;

            // Search backward from right
            while (low <= high && list.get(high).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.toString()) > 0)
                high--;

            // Swap two elements in the list
            if (high > low) {
                E temp = list.get(high);
                list.set(high, list.get(low));
                list.set(low, temp);
            }
        }

        while (high > first && list.get(high).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(pivot.toString()) >= 0)
            high--;

        // Swap pivot with list.get(high)
        if (pivot.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(high).toString()) > 0) {
            list.set(first, list.get(high));
            list.set(high, pivot);
            return high;
        }
        else {
            return first;
        }
    }else{
        //same code, but doesn't convert toString for comparisons
    }
}
```

When I replace line 3 that's where the problems begin.

```
//E pivot = list.get(0);
//change to
E pivot = getPivot(subList);
```

Here is the code for get pivot:

```
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> E getPivot(ArrayList<E> list){
    if(list.size() < 3){
        return list.get(0);
    }else{
        //sorts ignoring case if the type of data in the list is strings
        if(list.get(0).getClass().equals(String.class)){
            if(list.get(0).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(1).toString()) > 0){
                if(list.get(0).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(2).toString()) <= 0){
                    return list.get(0);
                }else if(list.get(1).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(2).toString()) > 0){
                    return list.get(1);
                }
            }else if(list.get(0).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(1).toString()) <= 0){
                if(list.get(0).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(2).toString()) > 0){
                    return list.get(0);
                }else if(list.get(1).toString().compareToIgnoreCase(list.get(2).toString()) <= 0){
                    return list.get(1);
                }
            }
        }else{
            //same code, but doesn't convert toString for comparisons
        }
    }
    return list.get(2);
}
```

I am not really sure where to go from here, the only way I get it to work is if the getPivot method returns the first element each time, but then it serves no purpose. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested this method in isolation?  Does the `getPivot` method consistently return the right answer?  If so, then it's not the problem, if not, under what circumstances does it fail?

Comment: I did test the method in isolation, and it works fine from all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you return, when swapping to put the pivot in the middle of the list, you are incorrectly assuming that that the pivot is always in the first position. Because of this, you may lose the value which was in the first position of the list, and get a duplicate of the pivot value instead. You need to remember at which index you found the pivot, and swap with that index instead of the first index.

There is also another issue. When you initialize the `low` variable to `first + 1`, you are also assuming that the pivot is in the first position. You should not add 1 there. Otherwise you might end up with a value larger than pivot in the first position.

Comment: This helped greatly, I don't have duplicate problems now, but some of my elements near the beginning are still out of place. An arrayList of 9, 7, 5, 11, 12, 2, 14, 3, 10, 6 in that order comes out sorted as 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14. I suspect it has something to do with the starting position in a while loop, I will test it out.

Comment: @Hephaestus Assuming that you ran one iteration of partition, that is correct. The typical partition step of a quicksort implementation only sorts an array such that all elements larger than the pivot are to the right of the pivot and all elements smaller than the pivot are to the left of the pivot. See [wikipedia quicksort article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm). It does not guarantee that the partitions themselves are sorted. To fully sort the array, you need to recursively apply the partition step on both of the generated partitions.

Comment: I was calling it recursively already, I just needed to change the condition check for swapping the pivot and returning the value from > to >=, and the comparison in the while loop just before that from >= to just >. I instrumented every line of code to find where the problem was.